# Catching the timed out Exception raised by the __init__ method of the class ftplib.FTP

Tags: python, error-handling, exception, timeout, ftp

### Introduction

I have written a Python class which uses the module `ftplib`. In this class I have created a `private`  method called `__connect()`. Its goal is try to connect to a FTP Server.
Trying the connection could be raised many type of Exception. I have emulated some of these kind of errors:

- a time out error
- a `Connection refused` error because the host (that is reachable) doesn't run a FTP Server

### My code

The code of my class is store in the module `ftp_connect.py`, and the code inside this module is the following:

```
import ftplib

CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10

class FTPExport:
    def __init__(self, server_address, username, password):
        self.__server_address = server_address
        self.__username = username
        self.__password = password
        self.__ftpserver = None

    def __connect(self):
        try:
            if self.__server_address == None or self.__server_address == "":
                return "Server address error"
            self.__ftpserver = ftplib.FTP(self.__server_address, timeout=CONNECTION_TIMEOUT)
            return "OK"
        except ConnectionRefusedError as ex:
            return ex.args[1]
        except BaseException as ex:
            if len(ex.args) > 0:
                if ex.args[0] == 'timed out':
                    return "Connection timed out"
                return "Connection error"
            else:
                return "Connection error"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Connection timed out (the address 191.168.127.1 is not reachable on my network)
    ftp_export = FTPExport("191.168.127.1", "frank", "123456")
    print(ftp_export._FTPExport__connect())
```

My question is relative to the **Timed out error**. If you see my code (method `__connect()`) I have caught the Exception raised by an occurred Timed Out by the following snippet of code:

```
try:
    ...
except BaseException as ex:
    if len(ex.args) > 0:
        if ex.args[0] == 'timed out':
            return "Connection timed out" 
    ...
```

In the previous code I do:

- catch the `BaseException` because the exception raised when occurs a Timed Out has `BaseException` as superclass
- check the content of `args[0]` and if it is equal to `timed out` I'm sure that it is occurred a Time Out

### How to cause a time out: valid IP address but not reachable

To test my code, make sure that the address `191.168.127.1` is not reachable in your network, and use the following command line:

```
> python3 ftp_connect.py
```

If you wait at least 10 seconds you obtain the following output:

```
Connection timed out
```

### My question

Is it possible to catch the Exception raised by the `__init__` method of the class `ftplib.FTP` when occurs a Timed Out connection in an other way than by the generic `BaseException` and by checking the content of `args`?

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @pacmaninbw Ok thank you, but don't worry I paid attention to not invalidate anything of the answer. I modified the code just to make it more impersonal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## no name mangling

```
        self.__username = username
```

I don't know what's going on with that `__` dunder prefix.
But name mangling is seldom what folks want.
Prefer a single `_` underscore to mark it `_private`:

```
        self._username = username
```

---

## public API

```
    def __connect(self):
```

I was about to offer the same (`_connect`) advice.
Until I noticed that this is no internal detail,
this is the *only* functionality the class exports.
This method is *definitely* public.
Say so.

```
    def connect(self):
```

---

## singleton comparison

```
    ... server_address == None ...
```

Prefer to ask about the address of that variable with `is`:

```
    ... server_address is None ...
```

It's just kind of a weird pythonism, based on the fact
that there's exactly one `None` object.
You'll get used to it.
Or your [linter](https://pypi.org/project/ruff) will remind you.

Testing for empty string with `... == ""` is perfect as-is.

---

## raise exceptions

```
                return "Server address error"
```

First, please write a """docstring""" explaining what this method returns.

Second, shouldn't we `raise` rather than `return` the error?

---

## catch exceptions

```
        except BaseException as ex:
```

Ok, that just seems insane.
You're trapping
[KeyboardInterrupt](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy)
and SystemExit ?!?
No ctrl-C for you!

Prefer `except Exception:` rather than `BaseException`. Always.
cf https://www.flake8rules.com/rules/E722.html

> Is it possible to catch ... in another way ?

Oh, thank goodness!
So you *are* aware there must be a better way, excellent.

Set a `breakpoint()` and then print out details of the `ex`ception:

```
(Pdb) p type(ex)
<class 'TimeoutError'>
```

Good, we have a TimeoutError.

Simply use `except TimeoutError:` and be done with it.
Yes, you *could* examine its `.args[0]`.
But that will always be a boring "timed out"
message for a TimeoutError, so there's little need of that.

In general,
if calling code knows how to intelligently cope with a particular error (or two),
it should `try` to catch just those errors, quite narrowly.
Avoid the temptation to go wide and trap all errors.
Often it is best to let an unanticipated error bubble on up the call stack,
until someone deals with it or reports it in a stack trace.

Comment: Before version 3.10, I believe it raised `socket.timeout`.

Comment: @RootTwo Yes I'm using Python 3.6 so I need to catch `socket.timeout`.

Comment: @J_H Thanks I appreciated all your advice. I can't give you more than one upvote! :)